# Possible causes of rough idle after changing Oxygen sensor...?

Tags: power-steering, o2-sensor, idle, acura, tsx

Got a 2005 Acura TSX 2.4L that I changed the upsstream Oxygen(Air/Fuel ratio) sensor after the check engine light came on. Since than, the car has never run the same. Engine idles very poorly (randomly not all the time). Happens when I shift, come to a stop, or turn the steering wheel. RPMS fluctuate randomly from 500 - 1100rpms and then comes back to normal. Car feels like it will stall and shudders for couple of seconds.

Next, Check Engine light did come on referencing these codes:

- P2A00 - Powertrain - 02 Sensor Circuit Range/Performance Bank1 Sensor1
- P0135 - Powertrain - 02 Sensor Heater Circuit (Bank 1 Sensor1)

Thinking maybe it's a bad sensor, I went a purchased another new one from dealer and cleared the codes after changing it again.

Check engine light has not come on put issue still persist! I'm about to tear my hair out!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!